# Number of "swappy" numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math

A number is called swappy if it is not a palindrome, but swapping two of its digits produces a six-digit palindrome. For example, the number $813381$ is swappy, because we can swap the last two digits to get $813318$, which is a palindrome.

How many swappy six-digit numbers are there?

What I did was find all 6-digit palindromes, which would be $9\cdot10\cdot10$, which is $900$.
From there, I used $\binom{6}{2}$ to find all selections of 2 numbers, which turns out to be $15$. 
How do I eliminate all the over counts going from here?

Comment: What did you try yourself? This is not a "please do my HW for me" ... or even "Please solve this contest math question for me" site. Please show some effort.

Comment: You get overcounts in a couple ways.  One is if you swap matching digits, either because they are mirror positions or because they happen to match.  You also get an overcount because if swapping the second and third digits results in a palindrome so does swapping the fourth and fifth.  You also have to avoid swapping a zero into the first place.  I don't have a nice way to count them.

Answer (score 0):

The three places where the count $900 \cdot \binom{6}{2}$ is wrong are:

- You should not be considering starting with a palindrome and swapping positions $(1,6)$, $(2,5)$, or $(3,4)$. That leaves you with the number you started, and a swappy number cannot be a palindrome.
- You don't need to consider swapping positions $(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (2,3), (2,4)$. Their mirror images $(5,6), (4,6), (3,6), (2,6), (4,5), (3,5)$ will do just as well, and this way you avoid double-counting. Each swappy number becomes a palindrome in exactly two ways: if a swap yields a palindrome, so does the mirror image of that swap. The exception is numbers like $102210$, where the $(1,2)$ swap yields $012210$, which is bad, but the $(5,6)$ swap is okay - so we deal with those here as well.
- There are fewer than $900$ possibilities for the digits of the palindrome you started with, because the two digits you're swapping must be different.

Once you fix these three things, you'll have the right answer.